# How do i integrate a custom d3map visualisation into Microstrategy?

Tags: d3.js, microstrategy

I wanted to know what are the high-level steps to integrate a custom d3 map visualisation into MSTR.

I have the similar visualisation as mentioned below.

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html

could somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you should download the D3Map visulaization into C:\Program Files\MicroStrategy\Web JSP\MicroStrategyWar\WEB-INF. Restrat the tomcat and see if your visualization appears D3Map

Comment: That's when I have the visualisation working for MicroStrategy data. The question is what modifications should be made in the javascript so that by adding the external data the map should work as expected. In the link which I have provided, it has the static data for which the map is displaying but what i need is, it should be able to work in other external data also.

Comment: Did anyone try this out?